# Alert dialog inside list item click listener

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, onitemclicklistener

I have a list view containing some values. I need to generate a dialog on list view's on item click. my problem is , when clicking any items in list view dialog appears equal to the count of items in the list view. I just want only one dialog on each item click , which shows the corresponding item details.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    float due = (float) 0.0;
if(list != null){
         for(int i = 0; i< list.getChildCount();i++){
             View vie = list.getChildAt(i); 

        TextView amt = (TextView) vie.findViewById(R.id.amt);
        TextView alloc = (TextView) vie.findViewById(R.id.alloc);
        EditText ed = (EditText) vie.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String amnt = amt.getText().toString();
        String allc = alloc.getText().toString();



      // due amount is net amount minus allocation amount  
        due = Float.valueOf(amnt) - Float.valueOf(allc);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDial = new AlertDialog.Builder(Collection.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=Collection.this.getLayoutInflater();
        //this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout,null);       
        alertDial.setView(layout);
        final TextView dues=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewdue);
        final EditText received=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.rcvd);
        dues.setText("Float.toString(due)");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDial.create();

          // show alert

          alertDialog.show(); 
    }   
}
}
```

And also i could not enter values in edit text inside the dialog. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use for loop. You get clicked item as `View view`. Try following code

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    float due = (float) 0.0;
if(list != null){


        TextView amt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amt);
        TextView alloc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alloc);
        EditText ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String amnt = amt.getText().toString();
        String allc = alloc.getText().toString();



      // due amount is net amount minus allocation amount  
        due = Float.valueOf(amnt) - Float.valueOf(allc);


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDial = new AlertDialog.Builder(Collection.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=Collection.this.getLayoutInflater();
        //this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout,null);       
        alertDial.setView(layout);
        final TextView dues=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewdue);
        final EditText received=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.rcvd);
        dues.setText("Float.toString(due)");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDial.create();

          // show alert

          alertDialog.show(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: hey it works..but why I couldn't  enter value to edit text? I have to update one of my view in the list with the edit text value. please do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(posstion==0){
//showYourDialog have value 0
}else if(posstion==1){
//showYourDilog have value 1
}
```

Hope! It help you

Answer (score 0):

Dont use for loop inside onItemClick. remove for loop and you can get view object from the method parameters.

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
```